# Do have Openlayers map an offset on view center?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, openlayers

Once again me, LOL
Well, I have a problem; not a technical one that don't left me show the map.
I am using ol-ext library only for make my map looks cool with perspective. This is the result in a test app:
[image]

But, as you can see half of my map is on the top of my div html element. I want that my indications don't hide my map details.
Well, can I offset my map center (not geographical center but in regard to html div center)?
I need this behaivor because when map rotates this offset must be the center.

This is my map initialization

```
private async initPerspectiveMap() {
    //find center because is perspective map
    let location: number[]
    const loc = await this.geolocation2.getNativeCurrentPos()

    if (loc) { location = Proj.fromLonLat([loc.coords.longitude, loc.coords.latitude])}
    else { location = Proj.fromLonLat([this.lon, this.lat]) }

    this.view = new View({
      center: location,
      zoom: this.zoom,
      constrainResolution: true
    })

    this.pMap = new perspetiveMap({
      target: 'map'+this.id,
      view: this.view,
      layers: [new TileLayer({
        source: new OSM(),
        zIndex: 0
      })],
      integration: defaultIntegrations(),
      controls: [] //defaultControls().extend([]),
    })

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setMap()
      /* this.pMap.getInteractions().forEach(x => x.setActive(false)); */
      /* this.pMap.setTarget(document.getElementById('map'+this.id)); */
      this.pMap.on('change:perspective', (e) => {
        this.pMap.updateSize();
      })
      this.pMap.setPerspective(this.tilt)
      this.gMap.on('rendercomplete', (mapEvent) => {
        if (this.firstTime) {
          console.log('map loaded');
          this.onLoad.emit(mapEvent)
          this.showFirstFeatures()
          this.firstTime = false
        }
      })
    }, 100);
  }
```

I want my center projected more to the bottom.

Thanks a lot pals

Comment: additionally to `center`, the `view` has a padding option to set an offset in css-pixel, not sure how this would interact with the perspective of `ol-ext` though

Comment: But, I understood that view padding options, besides of offsets center makes a frame. I don't wanna a frame. Anyway, I will try

Comment: Besides the preferable view options to be passed to the ol.View, you could also use a div above your map to push the map down in total, wont that work?

On a sidenote: IIRC, there is a `once` event. You could use `map.once('rendercomplete'...)` instead of your `this.firstTime` logic

Comment: Thanx, I will test first recommendation, and the second one is genius,